# Удаление элемента из ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, коллекции

Я хочу использовать Iterator, чтобы удалить элемент. Примерно так:

```
List<Element> elements = obj.getElements();
Iterator<Element> it = elements.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Element el = it.next();
        if (el.getCounter() < minValue || el.getCounter() > maxValue) {
                elements.remove(queue);
            }
        }
        return queues;
```

Однако, получаю `ConcurrentModificationException` на строке 4 при втором проходе цикла.
Подскажите, как мне исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь методом `remove` у итератора - `it.remove()` удалит нужный элемент из коллекции. Только опять-же, если во время итератора в коллекцию залетел какой-то объект - словим `ConcurrentModificationException `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае, `ConcurrentModificationException` возникает из-за того, что Вы, итерируясь по коллекции, изменяете эту самую коллекцию.

Удаляйте элементы из коллекции с помощью итератора методом `remove()`, который удаляет текущий элемент.